# How to find a Minimum Spanning Tree with a given set of coordinates from an input file using Prim's Algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, coordinates, prims-algorithm

Alright guys, I have seen this no where on the internet and I have been trying to figure it out for days. How can I find the MST of a set of coordinates from an input file using Prim's Algorithm. There are a few things about how to go about doing it, but following them along and being new to C++, they aren't much help. Can anyone show me CODE(preferably) on how to solve this issue?

Suppose I have a set of coordinates in an input file "Something.txt" containing:
(N number of nodes/vertices)
(x Coord), (y coord)
etc...

Eg:

```
9
50 100
100 150
200 150
300 150
350 100
300 50
200 50
100 50
150 100
```

Given that these points have already been plotted, How would Prim's Algorithm be written? I understand this is a lot, but I'm beyond confused at this point as a new learner to C++. (and yes, I've tried piecing out the code, I've tried looking at other examples and twisting them around to get it to work, I've tried just about everything besides seeing how it's done so I can further understand what I keep missing.)

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The code plotting the points through pygraphics using the argument .txt input file you pass to it, which then goes into a .dat file, which then gets posted through a plotting file pre-created:

```
class Point
{

    public:

        // Constructor.
        Point()
        {
            x = 0; y = 0;  
        } // end constructor
        Point(int a, int b, int id)
        {
            x = a; y = b; pointID = id;
        } // end constructor

        int getX() { return x; }
        int getY() { return y; }
        int getID() { return pointID; }
        string data;

        Point(string x)
        {
            data = x;
        }

    private:
        int x = 0; 
        int y = 0;
        int v;
        int xVert;
        int yVert;
        int pointID = 0;

        list<Point*> pointList;
        list<Point*> neighbors;
        //vector<Neighbor> myNeighborvector;

        //locate point containg value x
        Point * findPoint(string x)
        {
            for(Point * v : pointList)
            {
                if (v->data == x)
                    return v;
            }
            return NULL;
        }

        //add Neighbor going from x to y
        void addDirectedNeighbor(string x, string y)
        {
            Point * xVert = findPoint(x);
            Point * yVert = findPoint(y);

            xVert->neighbors.push_back(yVert); //I would think that this should only add y to x's neighbors, but when I try to display I  get x as one of y's neighbors
        }

        void addNeighbor(string x, string y)
        {
            addDirectedNeighbor(x, y);
            addDirectedNeighbor(y, x);
        }

}; // end class Point


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Edge
{

    public:

        // Constructor.
        Edge()
        {

        } // end constructor
        Edge(Point ptA, Point ptB)
        {
            pointA = ptA;
            pointB = ptB;
            length = sqrt(pow(abs(pointA.getX() - pointB.getX() ), 2) + pow(abs(pointA.getY() - pointB.getY() ), 2) );
        } // end constructor

        Point getPtA() { return pointA; }
        Point getPtB() { return pointB; }
        double getLen() { return length; }
        int getPtAID() { return pointA.getID(); }
        int getPtBID() { return pointB.getID(); }

    private:
        Point pointA;
        Point pointB;
        double length;

}; // end class Edge

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*class Neighbor
{

    public:

        // Constructor.
        Neighbor()
        {
            length = sqrt(pow(abs(pointA.getX() - pointB.getX() ), 2) + pow(abs(pointA.getY() - pointB.getY() ), 2) );
        } // end constructor

        double getLen() { return length; }

    private:
        double length;
        int pointID = 0;

};*/ // end class Neighbor

vector<Point> myPointvector;  // vector will expand as needed
vector<Edge> MinSpanTree;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream fin;
    int coordPairs;  // number of coordinate pairs in the file
    int ptX, ptY;

    int loopCounter;
    int pointCounter = 0;
    double MSTLength = 0.0;


    // Check the number of arguments. Expected: filename of a file
    if (argc != 2)  // This check is often hardcoded
    {   // If failure in parameters, offer advice for correction
        cout << "\nThis program uses command-line argument.\n";
        cout << "Usage: a.exe <filename>\n";
        exit(0);
    }



    try  // All lines within this block are part of the same exception handler
    {
        fin.open(argv[1]);
    } 
    catch (exception& ex) 
    {
        cout << ex.what();  // display standard explanation of the exception
        exit(0);  // exit the program
    }


    // Read from the file, one token at a time. If the type of token is known, it
    // can be read into a corresponding variable type, such as 
    //          in >> x;    // Read the first item into an integer variable x.
    //          in >> str;  // Read the next item into a string variable str.


    // This line provides the graphic window setup. 
    cout << "800 600 white" << endl;

    fin >> coordPairs;
    cout << coordPairs << endl;
    while (fin >> ptX)
    {
        // Do something with the element read from the file
        // cout << ptX << endl;
        fin >> ptY;   
        // cout << ptY << endl;

        cout << "circle " << ptX << " " << ptY << " " << 20 << " seagreen" << endl;


        Point dummyPoint(ptX, ptY, pointCounter++);
        myPointvector.push_back(dummyPoint);  // vector will expand as needed

        cout << "Now myPointvector has size " << myPointvector.size() << endl;


    } // end while

    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you new to programming in general? And do you *understand* Prim's Algorithm?

Comment: Not new to programming. I've programmed in a lot of Python and things like Javascript and HTML, and CSS. I'm just new to C++ in general. Worked a little with it and classes, etc. But I'm not very good with them and It's confusing for me sometimes. I can usually read code and be fine, understand it too. But when it comes to starting something or finding the start of a solution, I'm terrible. I understand everything there is about Prim's algorithm, just can't get anything done using this input file with only coordinates. Most of Google uses some type of weight. This is distance from Pt to Pt.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site where you can get people to write code for you. That's your job. If you have a specific question other than just "How can I write this program?", then ask that.

Comment: That was to be my next question; Prim's Algorithm deals with weighted graphs, not just sets of vertices, so something's missing. *Maybe* you're supposed to assume a complete graph with Euclidean distance as weight, but you'll have to talk to the person who gave you this problem to be sure.

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot to mention that. I AM supposed to assume a complete graph. And yes. Distance, rather than weight.

Comment: All right, are there any complexity requirements?

Comment: Not really. It would be nice if it used classes (probably vectors?) because that's probably the best way to learn what's going on for me at my level. When I mention that the points are already plotted, I mean that I have already written the code to pull the coordinates from the input file and post them to a canvas made by pygraphics. I can edit the question with the code that does that if needed. But pygraphics is involved, but I wouldn't assume would be terrible to implement. Thank you, by the way.

Comment: So I guess you can say the coolest part is that this will all be pushed through python so you have a visual of all the points and the MST being created. Pretty cool.

Comment: You have a choice of data structures. You must store two sets of vertices, and also store distances somewhere. You could have a simple table of distances and two sets of integers to represent the vertices (with an additional list of vertices for use in calculating the table), or a `Vertex` class, each containing two coordinates (x,y) and a set of "neighbors" (each consisting of an ID number and a distance). A set of things can be stored in a container, such as an array or `std::vector`.

Comment: The Vertex class seems more reasonable for this approach. Keeps things on my level as well!

Comment: All right, try writing a Vertex class that stores `x`, `y` and ID number. And a function that take two Vertices and returns the distance between them. Also, play around with `std::vector` a little, adding elements, removing elements, iterating over the vector.

Comment: Could you possibly supply some sudo code for that?

Comment: If you want to learn to write C++, you must take these small steps yourself; once you have `Vertex` and are comfortable with the basics of `std::vector`, we can work on building trees. Or if you want me to write the whole thing for you, I charge $100/hr.

Comment: I have created something of a class for Point(vertex) already. Not sure if it's correct or anything though. I've worked with Vectors before, so I have a pretty good idea about it. I updated the question with the class and added the rest of the code for the main() function. If you want, we can move this into discussion. Not sure the regulations on here, but I know they don't like a lot of comments.

Comment: Pseudo code (*not* sudo code) is just human language describing what to do, like a programming language with the widest possible syntax. If you don't know what to do (which I have to assume from your request that someone write the pseudo code for you) I'd suggest you read some tutorials and work through their exercises. Seriously, up to now you have pretty much nothing but a template which looks very familiar and which I guess you didn't write yourself, right? It's horrible code, btw, you should demand a refund.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will take a few iterations.

You have `Point` and vectors. Now write a function to calculate the distance between two Points, and a function to read the data file and produce a vector of Points. Also, write a class `Neighbor` that holds an ID number and a distance, and give `Point` a data member which is a vector of `Neighbor`.

Then give Point some member functions 1) add a Neighbor, 2) remove a Neighbor (specified by ID), and 3) return a copy of the Point's nearest Neighbor.

Once that's done, try popping one Point, **A**, from the vector, then iterating over the remaining vector, calculating the distance from **A** to each other Point in turn, and building **A**'s collection of Neighbors.

Put a comment on this answer when all that's working.

**EDIT 1:**
That's a promising start, but **it is vitally important that every iteration of the code be correct.** It doesn't have to do everything (or initially anything), but it has to 1) compile and 2) run without crashing. This code does not compile. In `Neighbor()`, you refer to `pointA` and `pointB` without declaring them; they should be arguments to the constructor. In `Point`, you refer to `vertex`, `findVertex`, `xvert` and `neighbors`, none of which is defined or even declared. (The `Edge` class is interesting, but it is not clear how you intend to use it.)

Shore up the `Point` and `Neighbor` classes (or abandon `Neighbor` in favor of `Edge`) so that they can compile and run, even if they don't accomplish much. I'll check back in a few hours.

**EDIT 2:**
There are a few features in the latest version of the code that may turn out to be unnecessary, but we shall see.

The idea is to build a tree, so how would that work with these classes? Try writing a small test function that constructs three Points (with hard-coded values) and assembles them into a tree. Once that's working, consider how you would apply Prim's Algorithm to those three points.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the code with some of the information you wanted me to gather up. Some stuff I didn't really know how to do though.. Like removing a neighbor and copying a neighbor. That's as far as I got. Does that even look remotely correct? Probably somewhat of a rough draft you can look at? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, as far as my end goes, the code update I just published compiles completely. I took your advice and commented out Neighbor though, so it might bee missing something. How does that look?

Comment: What's next on the list?

Comment: Do these points need to be connected? I mean, I already have points being plotted from the input file, I'm not sure how to create these points with coordinates hardcoded. Can't we just apply Prims algorithm to the points already plotted? Or could you possibly help with these points?

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and mark this as the answer too.

Comment: My suggestion was a simple exercise in tree-building, but if you're ready to apply Prim's to the real points, go right ahead. If it works, you're done; if you have trouble, retreat to the simple exercise, and if you're not sure how to hard-code three Points, try hard-coding one: just declare a Point in `main` (or in whatever test function you like) and construct it with hard-coded values.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all the help. I appreciate someone that can walk me through something and actually offer help, than just complain that I'm struggling and won't help. I'll take it form here!